# RegExp - Filtering strings based on the occurrence of a certain fixed pattern with changing values

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, filtering

In the context of a python application that is querying for records in a postgresql DB and filtering based on the value of a string/varchar field, and needs to do so in the fastest, most efficient way possible ( within reason ), I have the following problem:

having this kind of strings as input

```
"12:34|56:78|910:112"
"12:34|56:78|910:112|123456:54321"
"5432:12356"
```

where

- the pattern "[int]:[int]" repeats at least one time
- two or more occurrences of the pattern are separated by a pipe
- every pair of ints in that given order is unique across the whole string ( in that "12:34|12:34" or "12:34|56:78|12:34" cannot be an input string, but "12:34|34:12" can)
- the pattern can occur an arbitrary number of times

and given a list of int pairs such as `[ (12,34), (56,78) ]`
i need to filter the input strings so that

- the strings contain all the int pairs from the tuples, respecting the order of the ints within a single pair
- the strings contain ONLY the given int pairs (es> )
- the filtering process must ignore the order in which the pattern occurs

As an example, given the int  pairs `[ (12:34), (56:78) ]`, these strings should pass the filtering:

- "12:34|56:78"
- "56:78|12:34"

while these should not

- "34:12|78:56"
- "12:34"
- "312:345|756:789"
- "12:34|56:78|910:112"

As mentioned, this filtering process should happen while querying the database: ideally, i would be able to do it by including one or more regexps directly in the SQL query.
Even if this looks like a textbook problem, i could not find any obvious way to go about it, hence this question.
Thank you for helping!

As of now, the best solution i could come up with is using two regexs in sequence:

1. the first isolates all the strings where the pattern `\d+:\d+` occurs only N times with N as input
2. the second isolates the strings where the specified int pairs occurs , as in   `^(?=.*\b12:34\b)(?=.*\b56:78\b).+$` ( i generate the pattern from the tuples, so this is just a short example: the pattern could be way longer depending on the situation)

This method seems to work as intended and with postgres support for regexs in queries, it should be quite fast.
***I suspect, however, that there is a better, faster way to do it, hopefully with a single regular expression.***
Unfortunately, i don't know enough about regexs to come up with one on my own, as it looks like this is a pretty exotic use case (at least to my inexperienced eyes).

So far, my experiments were done in python for convenience. When the expressions' logic is confirmed, i will have to translate this to a postgresql query.

Here is what i could come up with:

```
import re

def occurrencesPass(input,occurrences):
    res=[]
    pattern=re.compile(r"\d+:\d+")
    print("isolating {}".format(occurrences))
    for i in input: 
        print(i)
        if (len(pattern.findall(i))==occurrences):
            #print ("include {}".format(i))
            res.append(i)
        #else:
            #print ("discard {}".format(i))
    return res

def digitPass(input,digittuples):
    digitsPattern=""
    for t in digittuples:
        add="(?=.*\\b{}:{}\\b)".format(t[0],t[1])
        digitsPattern+=add        
    patternbase="^{}.+$".format(digitsPattern)   
    print("pattern is "+patternbase) 
    output=[]
    for i in input:        
        matches=re.findall(patternbase,i)
        #print (matches)
        if matches:
            #print ("include {}".format(matches))
            output+=matches
        print ("look in {} / {}".format(i,len(matches)>0))
        #else:
            #print("nomatch")
    return output


        

input=[
    "12:34",
    "12:34|56:78",
    "910:1112|56:78",
    "12:34|56:78|910:1112",
    "910:1112"
]
inter=occurrencesPass(input,2)
print("INTER")
print(inter)
output=digitPass(inter,[(12,34),(56,78)])
for o in output:
    print(o)
```

Comment: You should bear in mind though that Python `re` supports a different set of regex features from PostgreSQL regex engine. E.g. word boundaries in Python `re` are set with `\b` and in PostgreSQL, with `\y`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I figure i would deal with all the intricacies of "translating" the logic in postgresql as soon as i confirmed the logic, but you just saved me an hour of headache. The main point though is: is there a better way to do the above than what i came up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind doing it in python, this should work. i would most definitely first convert your search tuples (int, int) -> "int:int" since the integers must appear in this exact given order...you could probably generate a dynamic where clause for your sql query by and-ing some condition based on the "int:int"...or some regex as your propsed (this might be complicated though since the "int:int" strings might appear in any order)

```
input = [
    "12:34",
    "34:12|78:56",
    "312:345|756:789",
    "12:34|56:78",  # True
    "910:1112|56:78",
    "12:34|56:78|910:1112",
    "910:1112",
    "56:78|12:34",  # True
]

# convert search tuples to a set of "int:int" str values.
search = set(':'.join(map(str, t)) for t in [(12, 34), (56, 78)])
print(f"tokens to search for: {search}")

for i in input:
    if i.count('|') + 1 == len(search) and len(search.intersection(i.split('|'))) == len(search):
        print(f"found {search} in {i}")
```

output:

```
tokens to search for: {'12:34', '56:78'}
found {'12:34', '56:78'} in 12:34|56:78
found {'12:34', '56:78'} in 56:78|12:34
```

**10/05/2023 update based on comments**
*if you can generate your SQL query dynamically*, sth like this should work: add a where clause for each *int:int* string that is part of your search pattern with negative lookahead/-behind to ensure it's not immediately preceded/followed by a number (handles cases where the substring appears at the beginning/end/middle of your values) and add a where clause that constrains the number of '|' in the value to n-1 (n being the number of *int:int* substrings you are searching for...here n=2):

```
select * from data 
where value ~ '(?<![0-9])12:34(?![0-9])' 
  and value ~ '(?<![0-9])56:78(?![0-9])'
  and (length(value) - length(replace(value, '|', ''))) = 1;
```

yet another solution might be to actually generate all permutations of your search *int:int* pairs

```
from itertools import permutations
search = ['|'.join(p) for p in permutations(set(':'.join(map(str, t)) for t in [(12, 34), (56, 78)]))]
# -> search = ['56:78|12:34', '12:34|56:78']
```

...and then use a standard *SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN (search)" query to search for the permutations directly...but well, if the values in your db and/or your search terms are complex, the number of permutations might grow quickly...

I don't think searching for all permutations of your search terms with a single *magic* regex is possible, there's no regex operators i know of that would allow you to express this...unless, of course you kind of create an OR'ed version of all your permuted search terms...but in that case you already know the set of valid values you are looking for, so you can dump it in an IN query directly (see above).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, due to the constraints of the overarching project, I need to be able to do the filtering part in SQL: i think that fetching just the id and the relevant string field for all records, do the filtering in python and then fetch the actual records i need would be too inefficient.

Comment: ...but you can generate your SQL query in the code dynamically? or should it be one single magic postgres regex that can handle a dynamic number of search tuples _and_ all their permutations?

Comment: i can generate expressions as needed in python (as in the digitPass function), but i need to use those expressions within a SQL query for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the attention :) The problem changed and became trivial in the meantime: the complexity came from the fact that the int pairs could be in a random order, so it occurred to us that if we sorted the ints pairs by the first term and then the second when creating the strings, then the filtering process would just become "string == string ?". Classic "duh" moment. Hopefully this question will still help someone down the line.